# Viewpager2 is not loading fragment on clicking tab ,but works on swiping

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-viewpager2

I am using ViewPager2 with Tablayout . Initially everything works fine. ie, both swipe and clicking on Tab ,loads the correct fragment. Say I have 3 fragments Tab A, Tab B and Tab C. I need to open other fragments from Tab B ,say Tab B1.Tab B1 is opened and on pressing back button it goes back to Tab B. Now when I click on Tab A, it higlights TabA, but the fragment for Tab A is not loaded. But if we swipe, its working properly . Below is my Viewpager code.

ViewPager code

```
private val fragmentList = arrayListOf<BaseMvvmFragment<*, *>>(
        TabAFragment(),
        TabBFragment(),
        TabCFragment(),
        TabDFragment(),
       
    )

    private fun setupPager() {
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(
            fragmentList,
            childFragmentManager,
            lifecycle
        )
        binding.mainViewPager.adapter = adapter

        TabLayoutMediator(binding.pageIndicator, binding.mainViewPager) { tab, position ->
            fragmentList[position].titleRes?.let {
                tab.text = getString(it)
            }
        }.attach()


        binding.mainViewPager.setCurrentItem(
            fragmentList.indexOfFirst { it is TabAFragment },
            false
        )

    }
```

Not able to figure out what's happening. Could someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case solved by adding `viewpager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` :

```
viewpager2.setUserInputEnabled(true); // enable swipe, false to disable 
viewpager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

In Kotlin:

```
viewpager2.offscreenPageLimit = 3
```